# I can't explode a text file in the format I need .. php

Tags: php, sql, regex, arrays, explode

I'm having a problem in exploding a text file in the format I need:

I have a text file in this format:

```
AUTHOR = cermin_mata post date=20 1 0 02 15 01 : 45 : 00.0
```

whatever........

AUTHOR = Oleg Butuzov  post date = 20 1 0 02 15 03 : 34 : 00 . 0

whatever........

I would like to store each post with its information in the database. So for example I would like to split the text file into posts, and store the each post in the same format( the author information in the first line and the post in the second line):

```
AUTHOR = cermin_mata post date=20 1 0 02 15 01 : 45 : 00.0 

whatever........
```

To do that I used the following code:

```
     <?php
     $author='AUTHOR';
     $word_escaped = preg_quote($author, '~');
     $pattern='~\b' . $word_escaped . '\b~';
     $count=preg_match_all($pattern, $fcount,$matches);
     $fp=fopen("ENG333","r");
    while(!feof($fp))
    {
    $contenet1=fgets($fp);
    $contenet=trim($contenet1);

     if (strcmp($contenet,"")){

          $contenet1=str_replace("،"," ، ",$contenet);
          $contenet2=str_replace(","," , ",$contenet1);
          $contenet1=str_replace("?"," ? ",$contenet2);
          $contenet2=str_replace("."," .",$contenet1);
          $contenet=str_replace("  "," ",$contenet2);

            //echo "'$author' occures $count time(s).";$author='AUTHOR';
            //echo $count;
            $posts=explode($pattern,$contenet);
            print_r($posts);
             }
             }
             ?>
```

the output I got is that:

```
Array ( [0] => AUTHOR = Fern pot date=20 1 0 02 15 01 : 45 : 00 .0 )

Array ( [0] => whatever........)

Array ( [0] => AUTHOR = Oleg Butuzov  post date = 20 1 0 02 15 03 : 34 : 00 . 0 )

Array ( [0] => whatever........)
```

While I need the output to be something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => AUTHOR = Fern pot date = 20 1 0 02 15 01 : 45 : 00 . 0 
               whatever........)

Array ( [1] => AUTHOR = Oleg Butuzov post date = 20 1 0 02 15 03 : 34 : 00 . 0      
               whatever........)
```

I tried to use file_get_contents() but I still have the same problem.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: i recommend you use xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this regex? It seemed to work ok for me:

```
/(AUTHOR.*?)(\n|\r)+(?<!AUTHOR)(.+)/
```